# Using Invoke-RestMethod with Start-Job does not send headers

Tags: azure, powershell, rest, authorization, azure-aks

I am trying to send parallel POST request in Powershell using Start-Job and Invoke-RestMethod.
I ran into a problem, when headers are not sent, when I call Invoke-RestMethod in a Script-Block.

When I use Invoke-RestMethod without the Script-Block like this:

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US")
$headers.Add("X-Correlation-ID", "TEST1")
$headers.Add("Accept", "text/plain")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer <token>")

Invoke-RestMethod '<uri>' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -OutFile "C:\OutFiles\File1.txt"
```

It works just fine.

When I use it with Script-block like this:

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US")
$headers.Add("X-Correlation-ID", "TEST1")
$headers.Add("Accept", "text/plain")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer <token>")
    
Start-Job {Invoke-RestMethod '<uri>' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -OutFile "C:\OutFiles\File1.txt"}
Get-Job|Wait-Job
```

The request returns 401 and when I look at the request in K9S, it does not show any of the headers that I sent.

I tried constructing the headers variable like this:

```
$headers2 = @{
    "Accept-Language" = "en-US"
    "X-Correlation-ID" = "TEST1"
    "Accept" = "text/plain"
    "Authorization" = "Bearer <token>"
}
```

And I tried using the -Authentication parameter for a Start-Job with a value "Default", because it said, it is the only value allowed for this method. Both things did not help.

For context, I am trying to call an endpoint, that is hosted in Azure AKS, if that makes any difference.

Am I using the combination of Start-Job and Invoke-RestMethod wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I using the combination of Start-Job and Invoke-RestMethod wrong?

The issue you're facing with headers not being sent when using `Start-Job` and `Invoke-RestMethod` in a script block is likely due to variable scope.

To resolve this issue, you can pass the `$headers` variable as an argument to the script block using the `-ArgumentList` parameter of `Start-Job`.

I have used the `GET` method and a sample endpoint to check both the `Start-Job` and `Invoke-RestMethod` in the same script block. In your case, change the method to `POST` and try the same code.

```json
    $headers = @{
        "Accept-Language" = "en-US"
        "X-Correlation-ID" = "TEST1"
        "Accept" = "text/plain"
        "Authorization" = "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ii1LST"
    }
    
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        param (
            $headers
        )
    
        Invoke-RestMethod 'uri' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers -OutFile "C:\xxx\Terraform\Sample Backen\File1.txt"
    } -ArgumentList $headers
    
    Get-Job | Wait-Job
```

**Result:**

[image]

Once ran the above code, the file has been generated as below.

[image]